# .NET - How to validate a List with no values in the Model?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Model:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<IFormFile>? Files {get; set;}
   public List<int>? Participants{get; set;}   
}
```

This Model will be used in the Create View. The Files and Participants can be null or up to a certain Count.
The Participants are filled by DropDownBoxes:

```
ViewBag.Participants = new SelectList(userRepo.getAll().ToList()).Append(emptyItem);


<div class="col">
<label asp-for="Participants" class="control-label"></label>
 <select asp-for="Participants" asp-items="ViewBag.Participants" class="form-control">       </select>
 <span asp-validation-for="Participants" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
   <div class="col">
<label asp-for="Participants" class="control-label"></label>
 <select asp-for="Participants" asp-items="ViewBag.Participants" class="form-control">       </select>
 <span asp-validation-for="Participants" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I have eight of those Dropdowns and I want to read out their values from Participants in the `CreateViewModel`.

My problem is that the Model will not be valid if I don´t select all Dropdowns. When I select all eight Dropdowns it is.

**-> How can I make a List validate as true even if it has no values?** For normal types it is enough to just add an "?" after it´s Parameter... The same for "Files".

Comment: I have found something interesting, when I change the List<Participant> to Participant Participant1, Participant2, etc and use that in the View (8 times..) then the Dropdown does look differently. With the List it shows multiple Entries und with the single Participants I get the "normal" Dropdown.

Comment: Hi @SuperNev, I have tested your code but not matter I select some of the Dropdowns or even do not select any Dropdowns, it always validates as true. Can you pls tell us what is your .net core version?